# Bluetooth chat - example from SDK - stop working after turning on bluetooth

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, chat

Hi,

today I was trying to run example application form SKD named "**Bluetooth Chat**" . Unfortunately there is some problem - when I'm trying to start application I get message "**Application " ... "has stopped unexpectedly**". I case when I turned it without active Bluetooth I get question about activation BT and then ... again this information about crash. I was trying to run it on my phone connected by cable. 
What should I do in this situation when I didn't change anything in code and it didn't work ?

Thanks for help.

Mat

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest.xml, change the minimum SDK to 11 as the following

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of app is bombard app. they are harmful for your machine or mobile. Please uninstall, be sure only to install app that has valid certification.
For android be sure to check your hardware if it;s compitable with the respected software, as some times different hardware prefers different apps.

> My advice is uninstall or delete the app before it can harm your
>   machine
>   Take my answer please if you like

Comment: ok but other from "samples" just works fine  - so why is like this it just only one - this chat - doesn't work ?

Comment: No sir it doesn't work. Try to download form reliable network.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is because your android phone version and the sdk sample version don't meet or the version of your mobile is earlier than the sample you are running.

somethings in the bluetoothchat sample code changed in SDK 7,10,17 so for example if you have android version 4.2 you could problems if the sdk sample if for version 2.3.6.

and you will definitely have problems if the sdk sample is later than your android device.

Comment: I have Android 4.1.2  so i think it should work but still I have same problem that i couldn't even turn on this app because of this error after launching.

Comment: @matgod what is the SDK version of the bluetoothchat sample you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Please copy all of the codes below than paste all into **BluetoothChat**'s **AndroidManifest.xml** file in BluetoothChat directory (For Ex.: in *Eclipse*). It is worked for me. (I am using *Android 4.4* SDK)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.android.BluetoothChat"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" >
    <activity android:name=".BluetoothChat"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
              android:label="@string/select_device"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
</application>
```